# Removing a hard Enter from a String

Tags: java, string, java-7

What is the best way to remove a hard enter from a String?

**Input:**

```
String in= "strengthened columns 
with GRPES
";
```

**Expected output:** strengthened columns with GRPES

I tried the below code, but it's not working for me.

```
in = in.replaceAll("\\r\\n","");
System.out.println(in);
```

Comment: `\r\n` is not the only possible variant. It could be just one `\n` char in there. But also - if you aren't getting the correct output - what DO you get?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov, I tried, but I'm not getting the correct output.

Comment: In the regex, you should use `\r\n`, not `\\r\\n` (though `\\r\\n` should work as well). Please show the actual codepoints of the string.

Comment: `in = in.replaceAll("[\r\n]","");`

Comment: OK will add as answer for you to accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't escape standard escape sequences when you use regexes. Also you don't want to specify an order of escape sequences - you just want to eliminate *any* type of line separator, so

```
in = in.replaceAll("[\r\n]","");
```

With later versions of Java, that could probably be

```
in = in.replaceAll("\\R","");
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you don't have a specific reason to use java-7 today, Here's a solution using java 13 or above

```
    String in= """
                strengthened columns 
                with GRPES
                """;
    in = in.replaceAll("\\n","");
    System.out.println(in);
```

I have observed the question is tagged with java-7, do let me know if you are looking for a solution specific to the version

Comment: thank you for answering. I am currently using Java 7, so I tagged it as Java 7. I tried the code below (`in = in.replaceAll("[\r\n]","");`) and it is working fine.